# Is there a Clojure library to log and store into fluentd?

Tags: clojure, fluentd

I have found a Java library to log into fluentd, but can't find one for clojure. Is there any Clojure library to log based on fluentd?

Comment: Why not leveraging directly [fluent-logger-java](http://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-java) through Clojure interop facilities? There is but two methods to get the job done. Everything else (writing records to custom destinations, etc) is achieved with config files anyway.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment the answer is unfortunately, no. though I do use fluentd from Clojure both by sending messages over TCP and by using log4j to write to a log file and then having fluentd tail that log file. I found the tailing approach *much* more convenient though it has a significant limitation that all events from a single log file get the same tag in fluent, while when you send them over a network socket each message can have it's own tag.

If you can live with all events having the same tag in fluent from your clojure service then go wit a tailing appender. otherwise you get to use the java one or roll your own. We made one in-house and it was really not very hard you basically build a vector that looks like this:

```
[tag (long (/ (System/currentTimeMillis) 1000)) your-json-message]
```

and pack it into a protocol buffer and ship it over the socket. If I was going to start that project again I would choose the java library.